# Is it secure to store password in Phonegap App?

Tags: php, ajax, security, cordova

I recently started to make some iPhone applications using Phonegap. Due to my current knowledge of HTML, CSS and JS, it is an easy way for me to start learning and create concepts that developers can optimize later on. I stumbled accross [this blog post](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2011/11/10/Example-of-serverbased-login-with-PhoneGap).

Here there is a description of a simple AJAX login form. I have previously asked about the security with using AJAX as a login method and was told that posting password as an AJAX variable is risky compared to a normal page change. This is of course based on desktop web applications, and in this case it is about native phone applications. Is there also a security risk using AJAX for Phonegap Apps?

In the post, the author also mentions a method to store the password and username as local variables to make an automatic login next time they open the application. Is this safe? Storing the login details as plain text in local variables?

I took some time browsing around some websites to see how they handle login AJAX based. To my big surprise, they don't do anything but just post the login details as an array to their login server. Websites such as iCloud and Squarespace, do not do anything with the login details before posting them. Of course they have an SSL certificate on the site, but is that secure enough?

Comment: I would `post` it to `php`, do a `sha512` and save that...

Comment: So posting the variables as clear text to a server, is not a security risk? All user logins are stored encrypted in a database using php `mcrypt` each with a unique salt key. So at the servers, the logins are secure enough.. I was just wondering if posting the variables as `anb@test.com` and `myPassword` via AJAX is secure.

Comment: Sure `SSL` would do the job (and you get 1% better SERP at Google).

Comment: Okay thanks.. And then for the second question.. In the post it refers to store the username and password as local variables. Is that a good thing to do or should you avoid doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Well the main problem of this approach is that login credentials can be [sniffed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_analyzer) . 
You can prevent it, with a `SSL` certificate for sure.

Now for the encryption part, i have come to use [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) (instead of `mcrypt` that was referred), because it provides a mechanism to slow down brute force attacks and is generally a recommended encryption algorithm. PHP has [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) method (`PHP 5 >=5.5.0`) and it is extremely easy to use it !

Answer (score 0):

Store password is not a good solution.

I Strongly recommend using security tokens using JWT (json web token) that can be disabled without putting your password at risk. Oauth 2.0 is also good complete solution.

Communications shoud be secured at least with SSL encryption and Basic Authentication protocol to send token in every connection.